# How to remove observeEvent in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I have function that show modal with one input to change name that execute function when save button is clicked and I have validation bind to input:

```
editNameDialog <- function(input, value, name, save) {
  showModal(modalDialog(
    textInput("modalNewName", paste("Enter", name, ":"), value),
    title = paste("Edit",  name),
    easyClose = TRUE,
    footer = div(
      modalButton("Cancel"),
      actionButton("modalSaveName", "Save", class = "btn-primary")
    )
  ))
  validName <- function() {
    nchar(input$newName) > 5
  }
  observeEvent(input$modalNewName, {
    if (validName()) {
      shinyjs::enable("modalSaveName")
    } else {
      shinyjs::disable("modalSaveName")
    }
  });

  observeEvent(input$modalSaveName, {
    save(input$modalNewName)
    removeModal()
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE, once = TRUE)
}
```

I call this function like this (from server.R):

```
editNameDialog(input, "default value", "enter name", function(value) {
   other$name <- value
})
```

it work but when I execute the function two times the observer input$modalNewName is executed two times for each keypress. How can I remove the event before adding new one?

Comment: Can you post a minimally reproducible example?

Comment: @mlegge I've removed functions that was not needed.

Comment: reproducible example as in the minimum server and ui object for the entire app to run

Comment: @mlegge the ui can be empty and server can have just that function.

Comment: If you search how remove event, we in our app ended up with overwriting observeEvent function that remove previous event, we copied te code from shiny source code and modify accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by adding validation in javascript:

```
function observeModalName() {
  var save = $('#modalSaveName');
  $('#modalNewName').off('keyup').on('keyup', function() {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.val().length < 5) {
      save.disable();
      self.error({message: 'Name must be at least 5 characters long'});
    } else {
      save.enable();
      self.error('remove');
    }
  });
}
```

and executed:

```
shinyjs::runjs("observeModalName()")
```